# Split and fade an MP3 file with JLayer

Tags: java, audio, mp3, jmf, jlayer

I want to extract some music (from second x to y) from an MP3 file and add some fade-in and fade-out effects.  Can I do this with JLayer?

So far I only know how to play a song with this library.

Answer (score 2):

Check this player ( http://sirk.sytes.net/software/apps/kj/index.htm ) it JLayer-based and open source and can (as they say) fade effect.